# Hows come upper radiator hose is so hot?

Tags: ford, coolant, overheating, radiator, head-gasket

I'm bubba.  I got a 5.4 v8 ford van from 1998.  I just replaced a cracked radiator on it.

But now, I swear my upper radiator hose is hotter than it outta be.

My odb-ii  computer scanner says the coolant temp is 192.2 at the mostest.

However... i wouldn't expect if I stuck my hand in some 192.2 water just as an experiment that it would reallt be a thang.

... but when i stick my hand on the upper radiator hose and it is L I T E R A L L Y hotter than the sun.

Actually , not literally hotter than the sun cuz well... that would a straight up dumb ass thing to say since the sun is "literally" billions of degrees and my eyebrows woulda melted even if I come a million miles in proximity of it.... But I guess I'm just usin the word for emphasis like the kids do nowdays.  It's HOT is what I mean.  If I was artistic about it... I'd say it was "hot like a hot place."

But, anyway... I cain't even hold onto it for more than half a second before it becomes unbearbaly hot ya understand?

You know?

I think I could fry an egg on it.

However my odb-ii computer syays its 192.2 and the dash needle is in the normal place.

But... I'm scared... cuz... I used to have a Honda civic (1998 also... good year, I guess)... and I remember my nightmare began with a radiator replacement... then it led to a upper radiator hose explosion.. then head gasket diagnosis...

...oh god somebody elighten me please.

Comment: " stuck my hand in some 192.2 water just as an experiment" I dont believe you. Putting your hand in 190 degree water for *less than one second* would give you third degree burns.

Comment: @alephzero lol.

Comment: You’re just mocking the members! You started the post about a workshop running a radiator flush as a scam and selling a reservoir (coolant) was as good as theft. You never mentioned anything there. In fairness any clogged lines may lead to an explosion of rubber hoses at the highest pressure point. Since you already knew it is at the upper hose, check where it passes to next in line and work your way around. Sometimes a weak or failing water pump might be the cause, your case is more about the clog and rusting metal.

Comment: Are the radiator fans working?

Comment: Hells yeah they always on. I think the previous owner done paper clipped it or sum.

Comment: On second thought... I believe on these vans the fan axle is connected directly to a wheel turned by the drive belt... so it would take a serious tragedy for it to stop turnin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical 50:50 glycol mix under normal operating pressure can be over 200F. That would feel very hot. Typically 120 F is the hottest water a person can stand for more than several seconds. Get an infra-red thermometer , great for a wide range of temperatures without contact. Helpful for making fudge. I drove my 3.5 L Murano about 12 miles on interstate with AC on , air temp 95 F : pulled into a parking area and measured the upper hose temperature as 188 to 192 F depending on where the sensor was pointed ( on the hose). Presumably the antifreeze was a few to several degrees higher.